# Google Maps API - Markers to Directions Route Service

Tags: javascript, maps

I am trying to add additional markers (custom icons) to my directional Google maps, but I cant seem to add these outside the initialize() function.

I need to add them outside the initialize() function, because I would like to icons to change based on the route. It's the ADD EXTRA MARKERS TEST which I'm having trouble with. All the rest of the script works perfectly.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Code so far:

```
       var directionDisplay;
       var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
       var stepDisplay;



        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( <? echo $lat; ?> , <? echo $lon; ?> );
            var rendererOptions = {draggable: true};
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
            var myOptions = {zoom: 14,center: latlng,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,mapTypeControl: false};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);  
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
                 }
```

//calcRoute

```
        function calcRoute() {
            var travelMode = 'DRIVING';
            var start = $("#routeStart").val();
            var via = $("#routeVia2").val();
            var end = $("#routeVia").val();
            var waypoints = [];
            if (via != '') {waypoints.push({location: via,stopover: true});
            }
            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                waypoints: waypoints,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode[travelMode]
            };
```

//DISPLAY ROUTE AND PASS LATLNG TO PHP FILE FOR FURTHER PROCESSING

```
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {            
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    var myRoute = response.routes[0];
    var txtDir = '';
    for (var i=0; i<myRoute.legs[0].steps.length; i++) {
    txtDir += myRoute.legs[0].steps[i].path+"";                             
    }
var strLAT = "" + txtDir;
```

//SEND DATA TO URL PHP FILE

```
     var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
     xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
     HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
     }}                     
     xmlHttp.open("POST",'MYPHPFILE',true);
     xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     xmlHttp.send("LATLON="+strLAT);
```

//ALERT TEST TO ENSURE PHP PROCESSED DATA CORRECTLY

```
    function HandleResponse(response) {
            document.getElementById('ResponseDiv').innerHTML = response;
            alert($('#ResponseDiv').text());
        }
```

ADD EXTRA MARKERS TEST

```
      var wxlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( 52 , -1 );
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            position: wxlatlng, 
            map: map, 
            icon: "http://nwsgeo.com/demo/images/pins/road-closed.jpg", 
            title: "test icon", 

     });
```

//ERROR MESSAGES

```
     }else{
     if (status == 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
     alert('No route could be found between the origin and destination.');
     }else if(status == 'INVALID_REQUEST') {
     alert('The DirectionsRequest provided was invalid.');
     }else{
     alert("There was an unknown error in your request. Requeststatus: nn" + status);
     }}});}
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure but your map var should be global, atm it is defined inside the initialize and therefore not visible for your markerstest

Comment: Hi, I'm not to sure what you mean.

Comment: in your "ADD EXTRA MARKERS TEST" you reference the variable map (in the marker you create), but this variable doesn't exist there because it was defined inside the initialize function. define var map outside of the initialize to access it at the position where you create the marker

Comment: every time I move the define map outside the initialize function, the map fails to load. :-(

Comment: If I move ADD EXTRA MARKERS TEST within the initialize function, this works OK, but I wont be able to change the icons, per route. If I move define map outside the initialize function, the map wont load..

Comment: No, but I just did!! - haha your awesome, I'm sitting here with a big cheesy grin on my face now. That bit of code had been bugging me for ages. Many thanks. -)